# Dragging home button opens Google Search - How do I remove this?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-search

Ever since I bought my tablet, this has been the default action whenever I drag the home button up (this is a soft button: on screen). I do not want this functionality because I frequently drag it by accident whenever I play games. This will bring up Google Search and interrupt my game.

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>When dragging homescreen, a half-circle with Google on top appears / Google Search brought up (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Again, how do I disable this behavior?

If it helps, I am using a Pipo U1 Pro tablet with the default OS (not rooted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Google Now Swipe Disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AdrianCampos.googlenowswipedisabler&hl=en).

> Google Now Swipe Disabler repurposes that annoying swipe up from the
>   bottom of your phone. If you're tired of having to press back twice
>   when your scroll gets taken over by Google Now, then have Google Now
>   Swipe Disabler do nothing! If you like the new voice search, but it
>   takes too long to swipe up and press the mic icon, then tell it to go
>   straight to voice search! You can have super quick access to your
>   camera, or maybe you're always needing to do complicated mental math,
>   now your calculator is just a convenient swipe away!